# How to write a function in Node-red for format Time

Tags: node.js, node-red

How to write a function in Node-red for format Time?

I have written something like this-:

```
msg.payload = new Date().toLocaleTimeString()
```

but the output is showing up `HH:MM:SS AM` or `PM`. I need to drop `AM/PM` from the end. Please suggest how to get output in `HHMMSS` format.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably to use something like the [node-red-contrib-date](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-date) node or the [node-red-contrib-moment](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-moment) node rather than to try and do it in a function node.

If you need to use a function node then you will need to use a 3rd party npm module like [dateformat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dateformat). To use this module you will need to import it into the `functionGlobalContext` as described in the docs [here](https://nodered.org/docs/configuration#node-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSONata expression

```
$now('[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01] [H01]:[m01]','+0300')
```

Last argument is Timezone shift